# Determine number of times variables accessed

Tags: c, cuda, gdb, memory-profiling

I'm optimizing shared memory in a CUDA kernel, so I need to determine which variables are the best candidates (that is, most often accessed) to be stored in shared memory.  I know I can page through the code and count the number of times each variable is accessed, but the kernel is rather complicated, so I'm hoping there's a way to automate this.  Can I have GDB count the number of times each variable is accessed in general CPU code or specifically in cuda-gdb?  Or are there other profiling/debugging tools that could be useful?

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you want to ensure that the most accessed values are stored in registers, not shared memory?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any performance metrics capable to count the number of times a specific variable is accessed by the involved threads. Perhaps you should have a look at the disassembled microcode (by `cuobjdump` with `--dump-sass` option) to be sure on how many times this occurs.

Consider, though, that in modern architectures (e.g., Fermi and Kepler), shared memory can be seen as a "controlled L1 cache", so its use may be not necessary if the variables are not evicted from L1. To have an idea on how frequently the global memory variables are evicted from L1 cache, you may have a look at some performance metrics of `nvprof` if you do not want to count the access number manually. For example, you may consider `global_cache_replay_overhead`, `gld_efficiency`, `gst_efficiency` etc. You may find the full list of performance metrics at [Metrics Reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference).

Finally, as suggested by @talonmies, you may wish to consider using registers instead of shared memory for some frequently used variables to have an even faster access.